# Programming time in Python

Tags: python

I want to program time that is independent and runs by itself in the background and ticks every second, and automatically changes Date every 24 seconds (1 second = 1 hour)

```
def PrintTime():
    D = 1
    M = 1
    Y = 2019
    print(D,"/",M,"/",Y)
    Time = 0
    while Time < 24:
        Time += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if Time == 24:
            Time = 0
            D += 1
            M += 1
            if M in list[2,4,6,9,11] and D > 30:
                D = 1
            if M in list[1,3,5,7,8,10,12] and D > 31:
                D = 1
            if M > 12:
                M = 1
                Y += 1
```

This is the idea I had in mind, but the problem with this is the whole program would be sleeping every second, which is what I don't want to happen. Instead I want to run this by itself, in the background, without bothering the rest of the program.

Comment: Just checking that you're aware of the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module?

Comment: Actually no, can  you fill me up on that? EDIT: Never mind I can just click on the link

Comment: Check the link in my first comment (I edited it in)

Comment: None of this would guarantee that 1 second is exactly one hour. Your clock will likely lag behind more and more over time.

Comment: You should probably use a monotonic system clock and multiply it by whatever factor you want to speed it up by; but that depends on what purpose exactly you need this for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `threading`  module to start a thread running your function with other code simultaneously. For example like this:

```
import threading
import time


def PrintTime():
    D = 1
    M = 1
    Y = 2019
    print(D, "/", M, "/", Y)
    Time = 0
    while Time < 24:
        print("Background thread: Time=", Time)
        Time += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if Time == 24:
            Time = 0
            D += 1
            M += 1
            if M in list[2, 4, 6, 9, 11] and D > 30:
                D = 1
            if M in list[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12] and D > 31:
                D = 1
            if M > 12:
                M = 1


thread = threading.Thread(target=PrintTime)
thread.start()

for i in range(10):
    print("do sth else", i)
    time.sleep(.7)
```

Comment: What does the "for i in range(10)" at the end do?

Comment: This is just example code so that you can see that the background thread is running while your program does some other work.

Comment: @Justauser did this help ?

Comment: It's working well for now, I'll update you if anything goes wrong because this is for my NEA coursework for school